# pip installs packages, but doesn't mark them as executable, so python doesn't find them

Tags: python, pip, redhat, sudo

I've been trying to use sudo to install python packages on a system that I am on the sudoers list, but don't have general root access (i.e. don't have the password for su). I can install packages, for example

```
sudo pip install django
```

however when I try and use them python simply claims not to have the package installed. Investigating the contents of /usr/lib/python it appears that other packages directories and .eggs have executable permissions for ugo, however the packages I install using sudo pip do not have this permission. Manually giving these files executable permissions fixes the problem, but that is laborious, particularly when pip installed several dependencies that I need to chase up.

Is this a known issue? What can I do about it? For the record this is a RHEL6.4 machine and I'm using pip 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is `virtualenv` Do your workaround to install the `virtualenv`.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

**Resources for virtualenv to get you started:**

http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/